# Highcharts exportar dateformat

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

Uso highcharts v6.1.4 puedo exportar sin problemas pero no encuentro la forma de darle formato a la fecha que traspaso a mi cvs , xls y tabla me aparecen en formato con numeros unixtime ejemplo:

```
1538917920000;19,3
1538917980000;19,5
1538918040000;19,6
1538918100000;19,5
1538918160000;19,4
1538918220000;19,2
1538918280000;19,3
```

¿existe una forma de mostrar una fecha en otro formato ? necesito que sea `'%e-%b-%Y - %H:%M:%S' => dd-mm-yyyy h:m:s`

probe con esto sin resultados :

```
exporting: {
            csv: {
                dateFormat: '%e-%b-%Y - %H:%M:%S'
            }
}
```

gracias por su atención.
CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script> -->




var chart = Highcharts.chart('grafico', {

    global: {
        useUTC: false
    },



     xAxis: {
        labels: {

           format: '{value:%H:%M}',
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },

    yAxis: { min: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
     },

    series: [{

        name : nombre_item,
        color: '#5c4ac7',
        data: processed_json,
    }],
```

Comment: seguro que no te funcionó lo de `dateFormat`? quizás debes darle a tu `xAxis: {type: 'date'}`  -> http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/export-data/multilevel-table

Comment: exactamente era lo que me faltaba , agregue lo que me dijiste y funciono gracias